# How to make accordion active item clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, accordion

After trial-and-erroring for the last couple hours, I realize I should really take a course on the basics of jQuery. Can someone help me with what will likely be a simple answer?

I am putting [this](http://wordimpress.com/super-lightweight-jquery-website-accordions-without-a-plugin/) accordion into a page, but I want the active panel to be able to click to close. Is there something simple I can do to make it possible?

```
(function($) {

  //Hide all panels
  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  //Show first panel
  $('.accordion > dd:first-of-type').show();

  //Add active class to first panel 
  $('.accordion > dt:first-of-type').addClass('accordion-active');

  //Handle click function
  jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {

    //this clicked panel
    $this = $(this);

    //the target panel content
    $target = $this.next();

    //Only toggle non-displayed 
    if(!$this.hasClass('accordion-active')){

      //slide up any open panels and remove active class
      $this.parent().children('dd').slideUp();

      //remove any active class
      jQuery('.accordion > dt').removeClass('accordion-active');

      //add active class
      $this.addClass('accordion-active');

      //slide down target panel
      $target.addClass('active').slideDown();

    }

    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
      //this clicked panel
      var $this = $(this), 
          $target = $this.next(); 

      //slide up any open panels and remove active class
      $this.parent().children('dd').not($target).slideUp(); //Slide Up everything but the target one

      //remove any active class
      jQuery('.accordion > dt').removeClass('accordion-active');
      //add active class
      $this.addClass('accordion-active');
      //slide down target panel
      $target.addClass('active').slideToggle();

    return false;
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T9bam/)**

And actually you can simplify this to:

```
 jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this) ,
            $target = $this.next();

        $('.accordion > dt.accordion-active').not($this.toggleClass('accordion-active')).removeClass('accordion-active');

        $this.siblings('dd').not($target.addClass('active').slideToggle()).slideUp();

        return false;
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N9c7K/)**

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but...isn't `.parent().children('dd')` just a longer way of saying `.siblings('dd')`?  I don't use it very often so I'm actually curious

Comment: Brillant. Thanks PSL and Deryck. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Even better! Thanks :)